# CI4 Getting started issues

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Decide to give the newly released CI4 a try.

Ubuntu operating system with php 7.4.3.

Following the docs at https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/installation/index.html

```
composer create-project codeigniter4/appstarter c400
cd c400
# Not sure if this is needed
php builds development
composer update # per the build's output
php spark serve
```

Which results in:

```
CodeIgniter CLI Tool - Version 4.0.1 - Server-Time: 2020-02-24 10:41:36am

PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class CodeIgniter\Commands\CommandsTestStreamFilter, because the name is already in use in /home/ahundiak/zayso2020/c400/tests/_support/Commands/CommandsTestStreamFilter.php on line 3
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/ahundiak/zayso2020/c400/spark:0
PHP   2. CodeIgniter\CLI\Console->run() /home/ahundiak/zayso2020/c400/spark:57
PHP   3. CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->run() /home/ahundiak/zayso2020/c400/vendor/codeigniter4/codeigniter4/system/CLI/Console.php:86
PHP   4. CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->handleRequest() /home/ahundiak/zayso2020/c400/vendor/codeigniter4/codeigniter4/system/CodeIgniter.php:306
PHP   5. CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->runController() /home/ahundiak/zayso2020/c400/vendor/codeigniter4/codeigniter4/system/CodeIgniter.php:398
PHP   6. CodeIgniter\CLI\CommandRunner->_remap() /home/ahundiak/zayso2020/c400/vendor/codeigniter4/codeigniter4/system/CodeIgniter.php:906
PHP   7. CodeIgniter\CLI\CommandRunner->index() /home/ahundiak/zayso2020/c400/vendor/codeigniter4/codeigniter4/system/CLI/CommandRunner.php:86
PHP   8. CodeIgniter\CLI\CommandRunner->createCommandList() /home/ahundiak/zayso2020/c400/vendor/codeigniter4/codeigniter4/system/CLI/CommandRunner.php:103
PHP   9. class_exists() /home/ahundiak/zayso2020/c400/vendor/codeigniter4/codeigniter4/system/CLI/CommandRunner.php:167
PHP  10. spl_autoload_call() /home/ahundiak/zayso2020/c400/vendor/codeigniter4/codeigniter4/system/CLI/CommandRunner.php:167
PHP  11. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() /home/ahundiak/zayso2020/c400/vendor/codeigniter4/codeigniter4/system/CLI/CommandRunner.php:167
PHP  12. Composer\Autoload\includeFile() /home/ahundiak/zayso2020/c400/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:322
PHP  13. include() /home/ahundiak/zayso2020/c400/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:444
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type:        ErrorException
Message:     Cannot declare class CodeIgniter\Commands\CommandsTestStreamFilter, because the name is already in use
Filename:    /home/ahundiak/zayso2020/c400/tests/_support/Commands/CommandsTestStreamFilter.php
Line Number: 3
```

The error is not unlike some of the errors Symfony was generating when preloading was first introduced.  But 7.4.3 has resolved those for Symfony at least.

I started to step my way through the spark console code but thought I would see if anyone else had run into this.

**Update**: From https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-75587.html, it appears that this issue is being worked.  I'll come back and close this when the fix is released.

Comment: CI 4.0 was released today, in a kinda rush. Did you check here? 
[CodeIgniter Forums -> CodeIgniter 4 ->CodeIgniter 4 Support](https://forum.codeigniter.com/forum-30.html)

Comment: Yep. https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-75587.html No feedback yet.  "kinda rush" after 4+ years of development? Hope not.

Comment: yes, because of the project lead passing away some weeks ago and today being his birthday, R.I.P. James P.

Comment: Sad but releasing software before it is ready is probably not the sort of legacy he would want to leave.

Comment: @MujahidBhoraniya Thanks for the edit but in many operating systems, commands are case sensitive.  So changing php to PHP is not only not helping but is actually breaking stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waited a few days for the fix to be released.  Did a composer update which moved me from CLI 4.0.1 to 4.0.2 but the problem persisted.

Made a new project and it all worked as expected.

Not sure if the composer update was supposed to work or not but at least the welcome page is now showing.

Comment: Have you checked the extensions mentioned in the docs installed or not?